# How can I delete a UV unwrapping to start again?

Tags: uv

I unwrapped everything automatically and it endend up being really bad for painting. How can I delete the unwrapping and start again?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can start again and re-do the UV unwrap just by doing the unwrap command again. In edit mode press <kbd>U</kbd> and select any of the methods. The UVs will be redone with the new method and the old UVs will be discarded. The mapping methods are explained [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html).

There is one exception to the above and that is *UV pinning*. If any of the UV vertices are pinned (they are red), you need to unpin them first with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. **Pinning prevents UV vertices to be re-done.**

Deleting the UVs is another thing. One mesh can have multiple UV unwraps and you will find them in *Mesh Properties*:

[image]

You can delete any UV map completely with the <kbd>-</kbd> button.

If there is no UV map awailable, the unwrap operator <kbd>U</kbd> does create one automatically when unwrapping.

Answer (score 13):

The steps are as follow.

1. Enter Edit Mode.
2. Select all faces ( <kbd>A</kbd> )
3. Hit <kbd>U</kbd> select "reset"

That's all to it. Your UV should be reset to the default starting point.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the uv map, it just kinda stretches all the uv area, making things even more annoying to work with than when I screwed things up before.

Comment: @Ram It is the question and the answer resets the UV. I think you guys were looking for a solution for a different problem ... OP wanted to "RESET" to starting point. That's all this step is about. It does not magically give you a nicely layout UV which is pure lazy on your end.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have a clean slate on your UV map window as opposed to doing a RESET and having a placeholder UV instead, press space and search for "Remove UV Map".

Answer (score 3):

In 2.8 in properties  choose Object Data  scroll down to uv maps you can delete your uv maps there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.93, click *UV Editing* and in *Object Mode*, select *Material Properties* and remove the material by clicking the minus sign `-`.