# Dirty UV Map after reset

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a UV Map and I created another one. I saw that all UV coords from first map remains in second UV Map and I have searched how to clean these coordinates. I found reset option but after applying this option, the UV Map it is not clear, it has some strange lines on background. It looks like in image below:

[image: How UV Map looks now]

How do I delete the second map to look like in the image below?(without backround and without any coordinates on it as initially looks)
[image: How UV map looks initially]

Upd: I tried reset, this is first image.
I tried to remove UV Map and create another one, it copy existent UV coordinates from first UV Map

Comment: Did you try: https://www.google.com/search?q=delete+uv+map+blender ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete a UV unwrapping to start again?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46965/how-can-i-delete-a-uv-unwrapping-to-start-again)

Comment: Updated answer. In that question is talking about Reset: result in first image.

Comment: If I will delete all UV Maps then result is what I want, but I have a UV Map that I worked so much...

Comment: "I have a UV Map that I worked so much..." - please clarify this. What you originally wanted was to delete the UV map to look like on 2nd picture, which removing UV map does.

Comment: I want to clear UV Map to look like in second picture, but I have another one map that I don't want to remove. Problem is how can I clear second map without remove first map.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I see now. Sadly it's not possible to do what you want, because the result you see on 2nd picture occurs only when there are no UV maps assigned to the mesh. Vise-versa if you see empty UV editor, you know there are no UV maps.