# Smart UV Project/Unwrap

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, axis, project

I'm having trouble using the Smart UV Project Unwrap in Blender 2.81. When I go into shading to check the Unwrap, I apply a basic checker texture and it shows a stretch in the Z axis. Why is this so? How can I fix this, make them square checkers.

See below:

[image: UV Project rectangle checkers]

Thanks,
CorzaX24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens, when your object has *non-uniform* scale.
You need to *apply scale* first for a correct UV unwrap.

*Object > Apply > Scale*

[image]

Also, make sure your texture is connected to the UV map

[image]

Comment: Have followed your suggestion, hasn't fixed anything :(
Also tried applying all transformations.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Weird, works fine for me :). Make sure to UV unwrap again, after applying the scale. If that won't work, you can [share your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and I can check what's wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to completely remove previous UV unwraps? Or does doing another one just overwrite the existing one? I'm new the blender if you can't tell.

Comment: If you select all vertices, it just overwrites the old UV map. This thread goes into detail: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46965/78972

Comment: After deleting any UV unwraps and applying a new smart UV Unwrap after applying scales/transformations, still having the same issues. I'll share my .blend file with you if you don't mind.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=O1S85aQ8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/O1S85aQ8/)

Comment: Right. Your texture wasn't connected to the UV map - it only used generated coordinates. I updated the answer :).

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help. Thanks!